# How to properly enable WebGL DEPTH_TEST?

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I can't figure out why the yellow square (z = 0) shows up in front of the red square (z = 0.5).  It's as if I hadn't enabled DEPTH_TEST, but I definitely have.  If the blocks labeled "draw red" and "draw yellow" are reversed, the red square shows up in front as it should.  But I don't understand why that's necessary if DEPTH_TEST is enabled.  Here's the relevant code:

```
  ...
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.depthFunc(gl.LEQUAL);
  ...
  vertices = [  // red square
                0.0,  0.0,  0.5,    1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 1.0,
               -1.0,  0.0,  0.5,    1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 1.0,
                0.0, -1.0,  0.5,    1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 1.0,
               -1.0, -1.0,  0.5,    1.0, 0.2, 0.1, 1.0,

                // yellow square
                0.5,  0.5,  0.0,    1.0, 0.9, 0.2, 1.0,
               -0.5,  0.5,  0.0,    1.0, 0.9, 0.2, 1.0,
                0.5, -0.5,  0.0,    1.0, 0.9, 0.2, 1.0,
               -0.5, -0.5,  0.0,    1.0, 0.9, 0.2, 1.0 ];

  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.createBuffer());
  gl.bufferData(
      gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

  // draw red
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 28, 0);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      vertexColorAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 28, 12);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

  // draw yellow
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      vertexPositionAttribute, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 28, 112);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      vertexColorAttribute, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 28, 124);
  gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
```

Comment: Some things you should clarify: Browser you're testing on; are your drivers updated?; Your projection matrix; are you loading identity on modelview?

Comment: Testing on Chrome and Firefox, NVidia drivers from Ubuntu package manager.  (All new enough that other WebGL demos work.)  I just have one matrix for model, view and projection in the vertex shader:  
  
  mat4 mvpMatrix = mat4 ( 1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  0.0,  
                          0.0,  1.0,  0.0,  0.0,  
                          0.0,  0.0, -1.0, -1.0,  
                          0.0,  0.0,  3.0,  3.0 );  
  
  [screenshot](http://home.messiah.edu/~owen/cosc487/temp/functions.png)  (Notice that red square is bigger, which makes sense since it's closer, but yellow is drawn on top of it.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you set the yellow square's Z component to 1.0, what happens?

Comment: The yellow square's bigger, as it should be, and it's still drawn on top of the red:  [screenshot](http://home.messiah.edu/~owen/cosc487/temp/functions2.png).

Comment: Try setting mvpMatrix to identity and then multiply it with a translation matrix to see if it solves the problem. Try this translation matrix [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]

Answer (score 3):

FYI, my matrix was bad.  I was looking at a book that had the viewpoint looking the opposite direction on the z-axis and got the projection part of the calculation wrong.  (Thanks Chiguireitor for helping me figure this out.)